# Float a flexbox to bottom or top

Tags: css, html

Basically the orange is showing, where i would like the postcontainer divs to be floating on bottom of the last div, instead of that space there.... eh?
You can see what i'm talking about here:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3BB7OOL4L4J

Here is the code:

```css
.mainframe {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
  //margin-left:10%;
  //margin-right:10%;
  //padding-left:10%;
  //padding-right:10%;
  max-width:100%;
  margin:auto;
  //border-style: none,solid,none,solid;
}

#top1 {
 background-color:purple;
        min-width:100%;
 flex-basis: 150px;
        flex-grow:1;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 height:40px;
 
}
#top2 {
 background-color:red;
        min-width:100%;
 flex-basis: 150px;
        flex-grow:1;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 height:20px;
 
}

#top3 {
 background-color:teal;
        min-width:100%;
 flex-basis: 150px;
        flex-grow:1;
 border-bottom: 2px solid black;
 height:20px;
 
}

.postcontainer {
 background-color:orange;
        min-width:49%;
 flex-basis: 50%;
        flex-grow:1;

 //border-bottom: 2px solid red;
 //border-left: 2px solid red;
 //border-right: 2px solid red;
 //min-height:20px;
 float:top;
 
}
.post1 {
 background-color:blue;
 
}
.post2 {
 background-color:gray;

 
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color:grey;">
    <div class='mainframe'>
        <div id='top1'>page title</div>
        <div id='top2'>search bar</div>
        <div id='top3'>cat name | cat name| cat name</div>
        <div class='postcontainer'>
           <div class='post1'>post title</div>
           <div class='post2'>post content
            post content
            post contentpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post conten
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class='postcontainer'>
           <div class='post1'>post title</div>
           <div class='post2'>post content
            post content
            post contentpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contennpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost contnpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost contpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post conten
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class='postcontainer'>
           <div class='post1'>post title</div>
           <div class='post2'>post content
            post content
            post contentpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content contenpost content
            post cnpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost contnpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost contnpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost contontenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post conten
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class='postcontainer'>
           <div class='post1'>post title</div>
           <div class='post2'>post content
            post content
            post contentpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post cont contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost contentenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost conteontenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post contenpost content
            post conten
           </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G3BB7OOL4L4J
It looks like my post is mostly code, but its a simple question. Here is more text to make it more interesting. Thanks

Comment: that would normally not be possible, what you are looking for may be a masonry layout... if your `postcontent` heights are *not* dynamic, you can *fix* using negative margins...